# Having problems utilizing Arrays and for loops in a Java assignment

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The program asks to "write a Java program that will first ask the user how many grades they want to enter. Then use a do..while loop to populate an array of that size with grades entered by the user. Then sort the array. In a for loop read through that array, display the grades and total the grades. After the loop, calculate the average of those grades and display that average."

The output is the issue. No matter what I do with the code, it will only output two of the inputs I have typed. If I chose to enter 4,5, or 10 grades. It will only show the lowest two. Although the total and the averages are correct. What is it that I am missing here?

Here is what I have written:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TapCoGradeArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int count;
        double inputGrade = 0;
        double gradeTotal = 0;
        double[] individualGrade; 

        System.out.println("Enter the number of students that are being graded.");
        int numberOfGrades = keyboard.nextInt();

        individualGrade = new double[numberOfGrades];
        count = 0;

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the grade (from 0-100) for each student below.");
            inputGrade = keyboard.nextDouble();
            individualGrade[count] = inputGrade;            
            count++;
            gradeTotal+= inputGrade;

        } while(count < numberOfGrades);

            Arrays.sort(individualGrade);

            for(count = 0; count == individualGrade.length; count++);
            {
                // This next line is using gradeTotal as an array. However, there is no array by that name.
                // Check which array this should be.
                System.out.println("The grades entered are the following: \n" + inputGrade + "\n" + individualGrade[count]);
            }

            double gradeAverage = gradeTotal / numberOfGrades;
            System.out.println("The total of the grades is " + gradeTotal);
            System.out.println("The average of the grades entered is " + gradeAverage);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ignore the comments inside the program. Those were teacher's inputs from earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two main problems

```
for(count = 0; count == individualGrade.length; count++);
```

this should not have a seimcolon and looping until this values is reached is correct.

```
for(count = 0; count < individualGrade.length; count++) 
{
    System.out.println("The grades entered are the following: \n" +
                         inputGrade + "\n" + individualGrade[count]);
}
```

Comment: Wow that was a quick reply! 

So I tried that, and that makes sense. However , the outputs show two numbers still. This time though, it is only showing two copies of the same number that I input last. 

"The grades entered are the following:
4.0
4.0
...."

Comment: I don't think you should be including `inputGrade` in that `System.out.println` because it's the grade that the user just entered.  You should only show `individualGrade[count]` at this point in the program.

Comment: And are you sure you removed the semicolon?

Comment: Okay so I figured out fully what was going on now. 

The semi colon was removed. I expanded the output window (Because Dr. Java only shows like 4 lines.) And it shows the same string displayed twice with the other inputs that I typed. So turns out I had to move the string to outside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. Definitely referring forum to this more often! I can't believe it took 3 hours for just one semi-colon that shouldn't have been there!